# How to display search term in grep

Tags: linux, grep

I would like to recursively search a file (file1) using search terms from a list (file2). File 1 contains a long list of items separated by commas in one column. I would like to create a new file (file3) listing the search term and the line containing the search term. Can I use grep/sed/awk to do this?

file 1

```
A, 1, 2, 3
B, 4, 5, 6
C, 7, 8, 9
```

file 2

```
A
B
C
D
```

Desired file 3

```
A A, 1, 2, 3
B B, 4, 5, 6
C C, 7, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner should help:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{k[$0];next}
         {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in k){print $i,$0;break}}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **awk** to save to *file3* use this code :-

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{k[$0];next}
         {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in k){print $i,$0;break}}' file2 file1 > file3
```

The contents will be saved to **file3** . use `cat file3` to display contents of **file3**.

**output** of `cat file3`

```
A A, 1, 2, 3
B B, 4, 5, 6
C C, 7, 8, 9
```